# Confusion in Mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

I am trying to display data of one student, i have a little confusion about mysqli_fetch_assoc, i want to display data of students i can do it with two methods here's my code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `s_id` = 1");
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

And i can display data like this

```
echo $fetch['name'];
echo $fetch['email'];
```

I can also do like this

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `s_id` = 1");
foreach($query as $row)
{
  echo $row['name'];
  echo $row['email'];
}
```

Both working fine for me, i can simply foreach without using mysqli_fetch_array or assoc, then why we use mysqli_fetch we are already getting array, and which method is efficient here?

Comment: You are only fetching one record so it does not matter. Try removing `WHERE \`s_id\` = 1`

Comment: i am using where condition to get one student data only.

Comment: No kidding, read my first sentence. When you need to fetch more than one record then make sure to follow the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#example-1953

Comment: i am not asking here about data i can show data using two methods foreach and mysqli fetch assoc , i am asking here which method is efficient if we can work from foreach then why we use mysqli fetch assoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer **mysqli_fetch_assoc** will fetch the records at once on the other hand **for each** will fetch a record on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Only difference is if you are sure about that record is only 1 than don't use `foreach` or `while` loop, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` can also be used inside while loop iteration but for multiple records, remember to always use `LIMIT 1` incase you don't want to use iteration (`foreach`, `while`).